# How to check if rectangle is intersects with another rectangle?

Tags: java, rectangles

How to check if the one rectangle is intersects another rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

There is an intersects method:

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r);
```

For example:

```
if (player.intersects(object)) {
    // player and object are overlapping, do something here...
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what to do :/

Comment: I made something like this : @whiskeyspider

`if (player.intersects(object)) {
   System.out.println("Contains object");
   timer.cancel();
  }`

Comment: But this the moving rectangle stops in the middle of the other rectangle .
Can you check why?
I will upload my all code to the question area.

Comment: Can you help me? This is not working the rectangle is stoping after move through 10 X dots. I can send you my hole code to your email.
My email is "yoavlevavi@gmail.com".
@whiskeyspider